# Deputy badge awarded with less than 80 helpful flags

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, flags

Have I been awarded the badge wrongfully or am I missing something?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you earned the Deputy badge with the old flag weight rules (>= 500 flag weight) then the badge wasn't removed when the rules were changed to just count the number of helpful flags.

Comment: I was awarded this in July last year, after being a member for 7 months, and I'm pretty sure I hadn't raised 500 flags by that time.

Comment: @Niklas - under the old rules you would have only had to have raised 40 helpful flags (1 flag = 10 points, you started at 100, so 100 + 40 * 10 = 500)

Comment: Ah ok! That explains it =)